# Pandas counter column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
Site           City         ...       Year_Built      Heritage_Site
a              Paris        ...       1887            Yes
b              London       ...       1858            No
c              Paris        ...       1202            Yes
d              New York     ...       1930            Yes
```

I then used the following statement to calculate the means for some of the variables for each city

```
df_mean = df.groupby('City').mean()
```

However I would also like to add a column at the end of this second dataframe which basically counts the number of occurrences for 'Yes' (in the Heritage_Count column) for each city. Something like what is shown below:

```
City           ...          Heritage_Count
Paris          ...          4
London         ...          2
New York       ...          0
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.groupby('City').agg({'Year_Built':'mean','Heritage_Site':lambda x : sum(x=='Yes')})
Out[489]: 
         Year_Built  Heritage_Site
City                              
London       1858.0              0
NewYork      1930.0              1
Paris        1544.5              2
```

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ  Man you do not need to , Yours is nice as well , BTW, thanks :-)

Comment: Same here. Deleted mine, too.